# In MVC3, is it possible to create reuseable functions in view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not talking about javascript functions, but server side functions written in c#.

For the html table in my view, I'm creating table headers that act like sortable columns. But the sortability depends on a complex logic so I want to put the logic into a function instead of writring it for each column.

@Amr ElGarhy
Thank you for suggesting customer helper, but the helper class I create is not being regonizied.

Helper Code:

```
namespace MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        public static string MySortColumn(this HtmlHelper helper, string label, string col, string dir, UrlHelper url)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    <add namespace="MyHtmlHelpers"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

But in View, neither @HtmlHelper.MySortColumn nor @Html.MySortColumn is regonized. Am I missing something here? I even restarted my pc.

**UPDATE**
adding namespace in web.config didn't work for me. adding in View page works.

Comment: try to add this on first line of your view: '@using MyHtmlHelpers'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to take a look at HTML Helpers and how to create a custom one:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-html-helper-for-an-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

Try this

[helper syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create base class with the logic and derive your views from this class. Normally you shouldn't reveal/share any methods to reuse between views.

Comment: the intent is to reuse within the same view, not share among others.

Comment: Why does this functionality need to be isolated to only one view?  Is there a security concern not metioned?

Comment: I'm creating a utility class/method for coding convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using areas? Areas have their own view folder and usually have their own web.config. If that's the case, you can try to add namespace to that web.config.

Also, web.config files are resolved hierarchically through folders. It means you can have web.config in your base Area directory which affects all area specific views.

In my case, I have two web.config files where I add my namespaces - one is in View directory and other one in Area directory.

Comment: I'm not using Areas. But I can live with adding "using" statements on top of View page.